# Too many hashing function collisions

Tags: java, hash, hashtable, hashcode

I'm trying to make a hashing function using the polynomial accumulation method (which is supposed to give you 5 collisions per 55k words or something) but when I run it with 1,000 words, I get ~190 collisions. Am I doing something wrong?

```
public int hashCode(String str) {
        double hash_value = 0; // used for float
        for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
            hash_value = 33*hash_value + str.charAt(i);
        }
        return (int) (hash_value % array_size);
    }
```

Comment: Aside from using double and 33, this is essentially the same as the built in string hashing method. Why can't you use that?

Answer (score 1):

Generally, prime numbers are favoured for hash code generation. I suggest trying 109 or 251. 33 is a multiple of 3 which means you are more likely to have issues based on your inputs.

Also you should use an int for the calculations and call Math.abs on the result.

Comment: "and call Math.abs on the result" why? hashCode doesn't have to return a non-negative number.

Comment: @AndyTurner true, however from the `% array_size` I am assuming this will be used as an index on an array.

Answer (score 0):

Either your data set is extremely "unlucky", or (which is more probable) the `array_size` is too small (hash function params are usually quoted without consideration of finite bucket array size).

Answer (score 0):

You are generating a large number which is different for different word in the input. But there is still a chance of collisions, as for example

```
"bA" = 98+(33x65)=2243
"AB" = 65+(33x66)=2243
```

If you go for a large number greater then 57, there will be less chance of collision. 109 or 251 will be a good choice.